# I need to make a string triangle with for loops taking off one letter of the word each time. Java

Tags: java, string, for-loop

I've been working on the code, but the only thing i can get in the output is a box with the word that i put in.
For example i need to enter the word "hippo" to make this shape

- hippo
- hipp
- hip
- hi
- h

This is what i have done so far on the for loop.

```
for(int i = length; i > 0 ; i--)
    {
        out.println(word);
    }
```

I need help please.

Comment: [Substring](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_substring.htm) - go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, the loop would look something like this.-

```
for(int i = length - 1; i >= 0 ; i --) {
    System.out.println(word.substring(0, i));
}
```

Comment: I know this is correct but I just think you should have given the OP the opportunity to try it for himself. Perhaps providing pseudocode instead of the actual code.

Comment: @JoshM +1. And also you could set `i>=1` to avoid one useless substring operation.

Comment: @JoshM Maybe you're right. Sometimes it's just easier for me writing a small snippet than writing a more elaborated answer giving my limited english skills :) Thanks for the tip, anyway, I'll keep that on mind.